# readFile reads my file after the rest of the code executes

Tags: javascript, readfile

Im hoping I colould get some insite. The readFile reads my file after the rest of the code executes. I need the information from the file in order to use it within the rest of the code. I have been doing research on synchronous and asynchronous but I cant figure out how it applies.

This is my readfile code and below it other code begins that is dependent on the data within this file.

```
const carPartlist = () => {
  const fs = require('fs');
  fs.readFile("doc.csv", "utf8", (error, textContent) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }

    for (let row of textContent.split("\n")) {
      const rowItems = [row.split(",")];
      console.log(rowItems);
    }
  })
}
carPartlist();
```

Comment: Use `readFileSync()` to read the file synchronously.

Comment: Put "the rest of the code" (whatever that is) in a function.  Call the function from the readFile callback, passing in your `rowItems` object.  Potentially horrible UX, but such is life.

Comment: I tried this before and tried one more time for good measure. I try to print file content to the console and nothing shows up. In the OP at least the file content prints to the console but after.

Comment: Pity you didn't provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Tibrogargan to you mind pointing out where the callback is? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: `(error, textContent) => this-is-the-callback-function`.  Read the documentation for [readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback).  It's the 3rd argument.  Also read the documentation for [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) which is how you should be doing this.

Comment: Better advice is to do it async within the callback, or async via the more modern library as I have suggested. There's rarely a good reason to block an app on file i/o.

Comment: @danh your suggestion 100% blocks the app

Comment: or rather, doesn't block.  But since the whole problem was that the app needs to wait until the read is complete your suggestion doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Tibrogargan - I don't understand either statement, please explain.

Comment: @danh the essential issue is that while your solution is correct, it's more than is necessary  in this context (also, the first iteration didn't solve the problem).  You've introduced the need for the OP to understand Promises and async/await when they have demonstrated that they still have difficulty with basic asynchronous concepts.  Simply swapping `fileRead` for `fileReadSync` is a sufficient short term solution, though admittedly it would serve the OP better in the long run to follow your advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to read async (to *not* block your app on a synchronous read).  Do it like this...

```
const carPartlist = async () => {
  const fs = require('fs').promises; // node >= 10
  const textContent = await fs.readFile("doc.csv", "utf8");

  for (let row of textContent.split("\n")) {
    const rowItems = [row.split(",")];
    console.log(rowItems);
  }
}

carPartlist();
```

**EDIT** maybe I'm being misunderstood because I ended the snippet where the OP's ended. The complete OP code probably executes code before and/or after `carPartList`. Work that must be done after can be coded one of two ways:

```
// at the top level
carPartlist().then(() => {
  // code here that depends on carPartList being run
  // presumably, the more complete OP code does something with the data it reads
})

// or, in a function
async functionThatRunsEarly() {
  await carPartlist();
  // code here that depends on carPartList being run
}
```

Per the OP's question (and contrary to some of the comments), this is the right way to do file i/o, this does not block the app's thread, this and does cause the "code here that depends on carPartList" (and the post-reading code in that function) to execute after the read.